# Olympus calls failing

Tags: restcomm

Local Install

When I use Olympus to call an app it disco's immediately and the logs report 'call-failed'.

If 2 parties sign in as Alice and Bob from external browsers, the call works.

The server sees external clients but they fail to connect.

I also have a cloud account and experience similar results except...
I would like to call an app in the cloud from an external client... How can I find the start URL for an app living in the RestComm (TeleStax) cloud?

any help or documentation would be appreciated

Comment: Hello, can you paste a link to your console logs so that we can see what's going on under the hood?

Answer (score 0):

For example, you have 127.0.0.1 assigned to Restcomm server, when you registering client alice in Zoiper you should provide following settings: User: alice, password: ..., domain: 127.0.0.1:5080. When you want to call to your app just dial the number that you assigned to this app in Restcomm dashboard (eg. +1234 for Hello play).